# How to lowercase first letter in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of text that is **camelcase** and needs to be **lower camelcase**:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| Original      | Desired       |
+---------------+---------------+
| OrderStatus   | orderStatus   |
+---------------+---------------+
| ActiveFlag    | activeFlag    |
+---------------+---------------+
| CancelledFlag | cancelledFlag |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
=REPLACE(A2,1,1,LOWER(LEFT(A2)))
```

Comment: fwiw, the worksheet's LEFT function does not require the `1` as the default is the single left-most character.

Comment: uh... yeah, worksheet functions rarely wins in code-golf but I did manage to tie you with my response. :D

Answer (score 3):

Here is a SUBSTITUTE version:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1),LOWER(LEFT(A1)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: You don't often see the *Instance_num* parameter of [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) used.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the first letter with `LEFT`, `LOWER` it, and then concatenate the rest with `CONCATENATE` + `MID`.

```
=CONCATENATE(LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)),MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: Alternate using & and the length of the string instead of relying on 99 being longer than the string in A1: `=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1))&MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))`

Answer (score 2):

Another to throw into the pot.

```
=replace(a2, 1, 1, char(code(a2)+32))
```